# Consume WCF service get error after the service change the return type

Tags: c#, web-services

I created the WcfService and it worked fine.  Now I need to to change the return value from int to List. After modified I get the error "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error" on my test webpage. Also the other methods that I didn't modify get the same error too. Would someone tell me how to make it works.

The page to send the request:

```
protected void getOrders_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         
        string serviceUrl= url + "/checkOrders?OrderNum=test123";            
        string result = ""; 
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl) as HttpWebRequest;             
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
             
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
           
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        lbl.Text = result;
    }
```

There is the code on my IServer.CS

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "checkOrders?OrderNum={OrderNum}")]
    //int getAllOrders(string input);
   List<OrderDetails> getAllOrders(string input);



 [DataContract(Name = "OrderDetails")]
public class OrderDetails
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<OrderDetails> lstOrderDetails;

}
```

Comment: So your OrderDetails has a property List<OrderDetails> in which each list item has a property List<OrderDetails> in which each list item has a property List<OrderDetails> in which each list item has a property List<OrderDetails> ..repeat forever.. ? Do you see the issue?

Comment: @PeterBons I deleted the DataContract but it still get the error.